# UIScrollView gets hidden when running on iPhone 4s and older

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, hidden

Why does my `UIScrollView` get hidden when I run my application on the 3,5 inch (iPhone 4s and older) iOS simulator?

On the iPhone 5 (4 inch) iOS simulator it's shown normally...

Thank for your answers.

Comment: is "Use Autolayout" set in your storyboard?

Comment: @danh yes. when I uncheck it, it´s shown.

Comment: @danh but now all my views and images getting out of position :-/

Comment: yeah.  you might need to go through them all, fooling around with their autoresizing properties.  or leave autolayout on and see if you can setup constraints (or code) that will correctly position the scroll view.

Comment: but where´s my scrollview going when activating autolayout?

Comment: Have you set auto sizing of scrollView?